# ASP.NET Membership Provider IsApproved reset to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

We've been using the ASP.NET membership provider in SQL Server for a decade without issue. Recently, potentially after updating the .NET framework and/or after a server crash, we started experiencing odd behaviour.

On a few random occasions, the aspnet_Membership.IsApproved flag was set to false to thousands of our users.

We carefully reviewed our whole code base to see what may be changing this flag in bulk and found nothing. We added a trigger to the table and confirmed that this event occurred a few different times and every time we noticed that many records were changed simultaneously (within the same millisecond).  We found that some users within the sets were repeated in the different waves and that these users were actually active on our site in the days/weeks prior.

Our server crash had the system (virtual machine) revert to a prior state and our users have cookies set to avoid having to re-login every time they visit the site.

The only theories we have are weak (.NET disabling users for some reason related to the crash) but can't seem to validate these.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Update: 
I added logging as recommended in the comments to determine the SQL statement which locks them out. The statement is the stored procedure aspnet_Membership_UpdateUser. Nobody had been locked out for about a month until this morning where 450+ users were locked out simultaneously by this stored procedure.

Comment: Were you logging the statement that was triggering the update?

Comment: No, just the event date.

Comment: PS: I didn't know logging the statement was possible; if you have any good references on how to fetch the statement from within the trigger, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Figured out how to do it via one of the comments here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46673 Adding to logs and waiting for it to happen again.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Something is calling the stored procedure: aspnet_Membership_UpdateUser

Comment: Have you searched through your code base to make sure nobody is calling this stored procedure manually, perhaps with incorrect parameters?

Comment: Yep, many times. We also had not touched these portions of the code in years. Furthermore, none of the locations that do access it loop across sets of customers - they only save a single user. I'm going crazy trying to figure this out! :)

Comment: I wouldn't be looking at something that loops, I would be looking at perhaps a missing parameter that was causing the statement to apply to more records than it should.  As you said, it's a single call to a stored proc, that means it's one statement doing it.

Comment: We looked at the code for that stored proc and believe there's no way it can do it in bulk. It has happened again today, after one month without issues. Very odd issue!

Comment: @JasonKealey did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have a situation where users seem to be set to isApproved=false randomly. I cant see anywhere in the code that could possibly be doing it.

Comment: @Keith I don't think so. Maybe my memory is off because it has been a few years, but I don't remember finding anything. I think it just randomly stopped or some other update fixed the issue that may have occurred in the framework. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯